# How to save "ą" in xml by python?

Tags: python, xml, unicode, xml-parsing

I have the following XML:

`newX.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
    <neighbor name="Austriaą" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="a" direction="W"/>
</country>
</data>
```

Python script:

```
# -*- coding: cp1250 -*-
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
xml = 'c://newX.xml'

tree = ET.parse(xml)
root = tree.getroot()
for rank in root.iter('neighbor'):
   rank.set('name', 'ą')
ET.dump(root)
```

I am trying to set a character 'ą' to 'name' but I have an error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xb9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

How to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a unicode value. Use a unicode literal with `u''` for example:

```
rank.set('name', u'ą')
```

This results in:

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
    <neighbor direction="E" name="&#216;" />
    <neighbor direction="W" name="&#216;" />
</country>
</data>
```

You are instead passing in cp1250-encoded bytes, which have to be decoded to Unicode, and that happens automatically with the default codec, ASCII. And that doesn't work, because your bytestring contains the byte with hex value `B9` (`ą` in the cp1250 encoding) and that's not a valid ASCII value.

You may want to read up on Python and Unicode:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Comment: It is possible to set      <neighbor direction="E" name="ą" />  ? (save in xml)

Comment: @user7172: use `tree.write(outpufile, encoding='UTF-8')` to write out XML with the characters 'intact'.